# macOS X weird python

Tags: python, macos, terminal

short Q,

In a mac OS sierra terminal,

If I do:

```
whereis python
/usr/bin/python
```

Then if I do:
`/usr/bin/python` it opens python 2.10

but if I execute 
`python` it opens python 2.7.8.

How can I know whereis python 2.7.8 and why whereis points to a different python version than the default one?

Comment: Do you have an `/opt` directory left over from MacPorts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run python and check the [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable).

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
```

Answer (score 7):

`whereis` only looks in a few standard places. Use `which -a python` to get a list of directories in your `PATH` variable that contain `python`. For instance, on my machine

```
$ whereis bash
/bin/bash
$ which -a bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
/bin/bash
$ echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

As to why `whereis` does not report the `python` that actually runs, note in my example that `whereis` only reports `/bin/bash`. However, `/usr/local/bin` appears *earlier* in my `PATH` than `/bin`, so typing `bash` alone at a prompt runs the first one found while scanning `PATH`. In your case, you likely also have Python 2.7.8 in a directory that appears earlier in your path than `/usr/bin`.

Comment: You should search or make a new question rather than modifying the question to whatever your current issue happens to be.  That way answers can remain helpful for future readers, rather than becoming redundant.

Comment: @wim I put the new Q here, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537880/change-python-version-in-terminal-and-intellij