# change python version in terminal and intelliJ

Tags: python, python-2.7, intellij-idea

short Q,

In a mac OS sierra terminal,

If I do:

```
whereis python
/usr/bin/python
```

Then if I do:
`/usr/bin/python` it opens python 2.10

but if I execute 
`python` it opens python 2.7.8.
and this one comes from 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`

How do I change the default python to point to python 2.7.8? In the terminal and in intelliJ?

Comment: just set the PATH so it points to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/` before `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the PATH environment variable with

```
echo $PATH
```

The python version you get when typing bare 'python' will be the first one found in that list of directories.

It is possible to control which python version is launched by, for example, rearranging the entries in `PATH` or by adding a symbolic link to the desired version in a position before the current version.

However, a more popular way to manage multiple python versions on the same machine is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/).  This will give you much less headaches when using `pip` to install/uninstall packages for particular python versions.

Answer (score 1):

As wim mentioned you will get the first python that is found in `$PATH`.

A nice way may be to `ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python`. This will create a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`

That way you don't change the order in your `$PATH` variable. Also note that if you `echo $PATH`, `/usr/local/bin` should be before `/usr/bin` - in case you have other versions in `/usr/bin` (which you do given your example)

I would strongly recommend you do what wim mentioned and use virtualenv to manage you packages.